# Overflow on a label

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a veriable which contains a string. I'm going to use a label to display the string. Sometimes the string can get very long, how do I enable it for when it reaches the border of the label, to continue onto the next line?

Answer (score 3):

Set the [`WordWrap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel.WordWrap) property to `True`. You will need to increase the height of the label to accommodate the wrapped text.

You might also find it convenient to set `AutoSize` to be `False` when wrapping is enabled. Otherwise you will need to reset the width to the desired value whenever you modify the text.

Comment: That's exactly what i did, for some reason it doesn't want to work.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work. Don't forget, it will wrap on whole words rather than stopping at the border. You also will need to adjust the height of the label to accommodate the new lines.

Comment: Works fine here. Clearly you are doing something wrong or have erroneous expectations.

Comment: I try it on delphi 10 seattle Have not been @DavidHeffernan

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  it work just when` AutoSize=True` and `WordWrap=True`  On **Delphi 10 Seattle Version 23.0.20618.2753**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using Delphi 10 Seattle.

**In this case Try to do :**

```
Label1.AutoSize:=True;
Label1.WordWrap:=True;
Label1.Caption:=YourString;
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Do we really need another answer saying the same thing? Version isn't relevant. Behaviour has been the same for ever. Further, asker uses 2010.

Comment: I just ask you because when autosize = false he did'nt work ! anyway thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernanI may also wish I could talk to you, as I did not find a private chat room Delphi

Comment: Why so? You can just make a chat room. But why?